# How find which element is drop using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i want two elements to drag and drop in a postion,droping position same.I want to identify which element is dropped usig jquery.Need to drag an text box and image.Text box id 'draggable'.Image have id 'draggable_img'.How find which elemnt is dropped?Any body help me?

Code

```
 <span id="draggable" >
<input name="" type="text" >
</span><br/>
<span id="draggable_img"  style="padding-left:10px;">
<img  src="../fancy/demo/1_b.jpg" height="50" width="50">
</span>

//drop
  <div  id="preview"
     <div id="drop">
     </div>
  </div>
 //drop


 javascript

   $(function() {
   $("#draggable").draggable(); 
   });
   $(function() {
   $("#draggable_img").draggable();
   });


    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'data.php',
    data:'page='+page + '&width=' + width + '&height=' + height + '&rows=' + rows,
    success: function(msg)
     { 
      $("#preview").html(msg);
      $("#preview").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".droppable2").append("<span id='draggable'>
          <img  src='../fancy/demo/1_b.jpg' height='50' width='50'></span>")
                }
            });
        $("#drop").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".droppable2").append("<span id='draggable'>
          <input type='text' name=''></span>")
                }
            }); 
     }
      });
```

Comment: You need to create a `stop` event in the `draggable` function. This will detect when its stopped. Then you can do what you need to do inside of this - http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

Answer (score 1):

See [the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop). The `ui` parameter has a `draggable` property, which represents the element which was being dragged:

```
$("#drop").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // id of the dropped element
        var draggedId = ui.draggable.prop("id");
        $(".droppable2").append("<span id='draggable'><input type='text' name=''></span>");
    }
});
```